# Mac Bash: how to combine the open and str subtract to one line code?

Tags: bash, macos

new to bash , I use the following code to open the super folder with a file path.

```
function openUp(){
  cd $(echo $1 | sed 's@\(.*\)/.*@\1@' );
  open ..
}
```

like drag a file to terminal, then open the super folder conveniently.

> openup /Users/de/Downloads/32/S01E32-array-arrayslice-collection-collections-1-master.zip

How to combine the two line code to one line?

I originally think open directly without changing directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `open` with an absolute path, it doesn't have to be a relative path.

That is, you could write the same in one line, with some basic improvements:

```
openUp() {
  open "$(sed 's@\(.*\)/.*@\1@' <<< "$1")/.."
}
```

The basic improvements:

- Instead of `echo "..." | cmd`, use *here strings*: `cmd <<< "..."`
- Double-quote variables used as command line arguments (in your example, of `cd`, and `echo`
- It's not recommended to use the `function` keyword, write without

A more important improvement would be to stop using `sed` to get the name of the base directory. Using a regex is error-prone and not as intuitive as the `dirname` command:

```
openUp() {
  open "$(dirname "$1")/.."
}
```

Notice that the arguments of `dirname` and `open` are both double-quoted,
as mentioned earlier.
This is necessary, to protect from word-splitting and globbing.

Comment: `open "$(dirname "$1")/.."` works perfect. while `open "$(sed 's@\(.*\)/.*@\1@') <<< "$1")/.."` get stuck there, just holding on. I tested in Mac.

Comment: `open "$((sed 's@\(.*\)/.*@\1@') <<< "$1")/..";` , lack a close parenthesis.

Comment: @black_pearl oops, typo, fixed it, thanks!